# Connecting USB-3 port to USB-C docking station

Tags: hdmi, usb-3, usb-c

All our meeting rooms are set-up so there is a single USB-C cable on the desk which is connected to a docking station under the desk. This docking station supplies video (HDMI), audio (speaker & microphone), network and power to the laptop. Works very well and users aren't tempted to keep messing.

However, this only works with laptops with USB-C that also support the alternative mode functionality, i.e. video/Thunderbolt/DisplayPort over USB-C. If somebody turns up with an older laptop that only has HDMI, they can't plug in.

We're looking for some adapter to allow them to plug this USB-C plug into their USB-3 socket on the laptop. I'm aware that we're not looking for a simple USB-3(A) to USB-C adapter as they just carry data. They need to carry video.

Before USB-C, we used devices like this. They are effectively an external graphics card connected via USB-3. Trying to find a device like this but instead of HDMI output, it's USB-C carrying data, video and audio.

I'm not convinced they exist!

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for an HDMI to USB-C cable adapter like [random example](https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Converter-Thunderbolt-MacBook-Microsoft/dp/B08VDT3YGK/ref=sr_1_18?crid=2GBA49U1ZADTA&keywords=adapter+hdmi+to+usb-c&qid=1666365113&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIwLjAwIiwicXNhIjoiMC4wMCIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=adapter+hdmi+to+usb-c%2Caps%2C149&sr=8-18)?

Comment: @harrymc No, that has the same functionality of the dock they already have. They're *trying to find a device like this* [a DisplayLink device or similar] *but instead of HDMI output, it's USB-C*. And no, AFAIK, there isn't such thing and that's good to avoid adding to the already very confusing USB-C usages.

Comment: @munrobasher Although perhaps you shouldn't use such, there are simple USB-C to USBA-A adapters that work for the DisplayLink device. Even better a proper USB-C hub with USB3.0 ports and then connect the DisplayLink device to that one. Or, if your docking station has USB3.0 ports like most, there's nothing wrong in connecting the DisplayLink device there.

Comment: I'm confused : There is a conflict between "older laptop that only has HDMI" and between "plug this USB-C plug into their USB-3 socket". USB-3 supports alternative mode.

Comment: Because they don't have USB-C video output on their laptop (just HDMI), they can't plug in and therefore a possible solution would be an adaptor that plugs into USB-A socket (to USB-3/Superspeed standard) that includes a graphics chip that can output via USB-C cabling. I agree with ChanganAuto, I don't think such a device exists. The Fresco chipset device above was about the only USB-C to HDMI solution out there so it's limited market.

Comment: I know using USB-3 to mean both the connector standard AND the speed is technically wrong, but the USB consortium was the source of that confusion, not me ;-)

Comment: Part of the reason for this post is that I haven't really a clue what is the technical description of the device I may or may not be looking for. USB-A to USB-C alternative mode adapter maybe?

Comment: I'd say you have rather limited yourselves by choosing to carry video solely over USB-C. You should have also made sure standard HDMI connectivity is available in all of your meeting rooms. With a standard HDMI cable you open up your compatibility to a much wider range of display connections through the use of all the available adapters that exist out there.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do and there appears to be no obvious solution for it other than to integrate HDMI into your meeting rooms. If it's for the clients then it's worth doing. Especially since HDMI is the current video standard and isn't going anywhere any time soon. Also worth making sure you buy HDR capable cables to future proof things even more.

Comment: >I'd say you have rather limited yourselves by choosing to carry video solely over USB-C: possibly but it was intended to keep the meeting rooms tidy. Another option is for guests to cast to the TV via Wi-Fi. To be honest, with the WFH mentality, we rarely have clients in the office